# Magento Sage Pay Module error : Error in payment. Sagepay says: 3055 : The CardType field is required

Tags: magento, opayo

I am using Sage Pay module for Magento, now when I try to put an order in TEST mode, I get this error : "Error in payment. Sagepay says: 3055 : The CardType field is required."

I am not getting any help on the reason of this error.
Help please

Comment: obviously, you need to enter the credit card type.

Comment: But I providing all the information already.

Comment: enable logs which is the 1st option in config>sagepay for the current edition. Then try to checkout, so an error will be reported.  The error is printed {MagentoBaseDir}}/var/log/SagePaySuite/" - open in a notepad editor thing.  If you have no idea what it is saying, print it here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Sage Pay DIRECT integration this means you are not supplying the relevant card type in your transaction post:

**CardType=VISA**

(The value can be one of the following VISA, MC, MCDEBIT, DELTA, MAESTRO, UKE, AMEX, DC, JCB, LASER, PAYPAL.  The value should be in capital letters.)

NOTE: MC is MasterCard. UKE is Visa Electron. MAESTRO should be used for both UK and International Maestro. AMEX, DC (DINERS) and PAYPAL can only be accepted if you have additional merchant accounts with those acquirers.